# Настройка загрузки СSS в Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, загрузка, настройка

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно загрузить или настроить загрузку css в Laravel, при условии что файлы css расположены не в папке public а вот по такому пути: storage/content/source/css/style.css

Comment: {{ Storage::path('content/source/css/style.css') }}

Comment: команда _ php artisan storage:link _ создает символьную ссылку на _storage/app/public/_, поэтому  _storage/content/source/css/style.css_ должен лежать в _storage/app/public/storage/content/source/css/style.css_ и выводится через asset()

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но у меня стоит задача заставить подгружаться стили именно по этому пути: storage/content/source/css/ .
Попробовал реализовать Вашим  способ, {{ Storage::path('content/source/css/style.css') }}  , но мне выдает вот такое сообщение:
 Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Это не возможно, т.к. *storage* ссылается на *storage/app/public*. 
Следовательно у вас один выход, изменить *url* на */content/source/css/style.css* и в *public* сделать символьную ссылку с именем "content" на директорию *storage/content/*

Comment: А как создать эту символьную ссылку? Пример реализации можете отобразить, чтобы наверняка понимать как это должно работать. Спасибо.

Comment: подключаетесь по ssh, в директории _public_ выполнить команду: _ln content <полный путь до приложения>/storage/content_. Можно также, например, через WinSCP правой кнопкой -> создать ссылку -> вводите имя 'content' и полный путь, куда будет ссылаться (<полный путь до приложения>/storage/content)

Comment: Спасибо большое.